# colored coding typing in text mate

Tags: text, colors, textmate

This seems really silly but I somehow hit a key combination by mistake in text mate and now the colored coded typing is disabled. It's all just black text no matter php or html or variables etc... I scoured google and messed with all the preferences and can't get it back on.

any idea?

thanks in advance

Comment: You probably change the source associtation to plain text... at the bottom of the editor window there is a dropdwon where you can choose the source syntax, try selecting the appropriate context (ie. HTML, CSS, PHP, etc.)

Comment: sorry that should have been an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably change the source associtation to plain text... at the bottom of the editor window there is a dropdwon where you can choose the source syntax, try selecting the appropriate context (ie. HTML, CSS, PHP, etc.)